# Cancel SwingWorker clearly with session

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, hibernate, swingworker

I have the following situation:

2 swingworkers with session which collect data from the database. Now I want to cancel the second swingworker. I do swingworker.cancel(true) and in the done() method from the swingworker I close the session with session.close().

After I have done that I think the swingworker has one sql statement which he is executing but he is cancelled and the session is closed so the following execption occures:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.getResourceRegistry(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.getResourceRegistry(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy9.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.scroll(CustomLoader.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.scrollCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.scroll(AbstractSessionImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.scroll(SQLQueryImpl.java:182)
    at de.mudisar.dataloader.SecondarySwingWorker.doInBackground(SecondarySwingWorker.java:71)
    at de.mudisar.dataloader.SecondarySwingWorker.doInBackground(SecondarySwingWorker.java:32)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What can i do to solve the problem. If i cancel the swingworker i want that all sql operations or other things should be cancelled and then close the session.

//EDIT:

Here is my code from my swingworker. This swingworker has its own session:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

doMappings();

fetchSQL();


}

private void fetchSQL(){

for(String str : map.keySet()){

    //build sql;
    SQLQuery q = sess.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity("ins", ALL_RSC_DATA.class);
    q.setFetchSize(Integer.valueOf(1000));
    q.setReadOnly(true);
    ScrollableResults results = q.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    while (results.next()) {

        //processing

    }

}

}
```

And this is my action (for cancel the swingworker) from my other class which handles the user inputs:

```
public Action cancelPrimarySwingWorker = new AbstractAction() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(psw != null && !psw.isDone()){
            closeDBConnection(psw.getSession());
            psw.cancel(true);
            psw = null;
            restoreData();
        }
    }
};
```

For the complete information here my code for closeDBConnection():

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void closeDBConnection(Session session) {
    if(session != null){
        try {
            //session.connection().createStatement().execute("SHUTDOWN");
            if(session.isOpen()){
                session.cancelQuery();
                session.clear();
                session.close();
            }
            session = null;
        }
        catch (Exception sqle) {
            logging(sqle);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your post to include a skeleton of the `de.mudisar.dataloader.SecondarySwingWorker` class showing how you caught the interruption, cancelled the query and closed the session.  According to the stacktrace `doInBackground()` has not yet completed, so `done()` should not have been invoked.  Without seeing your code, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry i cant post any of the code. I have a try catch block around my complete method. I close the session with session.close and cancel the query with session.cancelQuery. Sorry that i cant show the code. I hope we find the error without the code

Comment: Surely you can extract a skeleton of the code and remove any proprietary information?  If not, you may be on your own.

Comment: that doesn't help: what you need to do is extract an SSCCE which demonstrates the problem (mocking the db access) ...

Comment: :-( i think this is an SSCCE....my swingworker with the two important functions and my cancel action with the closing of the db connection / session

Comment: you did google the abbreviation and read the page, or didn't you?

Comment: i know what sscce is but which code is here missing? the doInBackground is there with the cancel and closing the session / connection and i have removed all other unrelated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(psw != null && !psw.isDone()){
        closeDBConnection(psw.getSession());
        psw.cancel(true);
        psw = null;
        restoreData();
    }
```

This sure looks to me like you're closing the db connection while the reader thread is still running, which would probably result in exactly what you're seeing.  You need to restructure things so the reader thread responds to the cancel and closes the connection itself in a finally block.